# Where statement on an indexed property takes too much time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query as follows:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid:"984172414"})-[ru:EB]->
(c:Co)<-[rf:EB]-(f:User)-[rc :EB]->(cc:Co)
WHERE (cc.uid in ["84161623"]) AND (rc.from IS NOT NULL AND rc.to IS NULL) AND
      ((
        ru.from IS NOT NULL AND
        ru.to IS NOT NULL AND
        (
            (rf.from <= ru.to) OR
            (ru.from <= rf.to)
        )
      ) OR (
        ru.from IS NOT NULL AND
        ru.to IS NULL AND
        (
            (ru.from <= rf.to) OR
            (rf.from IS NOT NULL AND rf.to IS NULL)
        )
      ) OR (
       ru.from IS NULL AND
       ru.to IS NOT NULL AND
        (
            (rf.from <= ru.to) OR
            (rf.from IS NULL AND rf.to IS NOT NULL)
        )
      ))
RETURN cc.name as coname,
f.name as fname,
cc.uid as cuid,
f.uid as fuid,
labels(f) as flabels,
null as version
LIMIT 20
```

This takes about 16192 ms to resolve. I have an index on `co.uid` but seems like it's not working. If I remove the check `cc.uid in ["84161623"]` and run the following query:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid:"984172414"})-[ru:EB]->
(c:Co)<-[rf:EB]-(f:User)-[rc :EB]->(cc:Co)
WHERE (rc.from IS NOT NULL AND rc.to IS NULL) AND
      ((
        ru.from IS NOT NULL AND
        ru.to IS NOT NULL AND
        (
            (rf.from <= ru.to) OR
            (ru.from <= rf.to)
        )
      ) OR (
        ru.from IS NOT NULL AND
        ru.to IS NULL AND
        (
            (ru.from <= rf.to) OR
            (rf.from IS NOT NULL AND rf.to IS NULL)
        )
      ) OR (
       ru.from IS NULL AND
       ru.to IS NOT NULL AND
        (
            (rf.from <= ru.to) OR
            (rf.from IS NULL AND rf.to IS NOT NULL)
        )
      ))
RETURN cc.name as coname,
f.name as fname,
cc.uid as cuid,
f.uid as fuid,
labels(f) as flabels,
null as version
LIMIT 20
```

The query resolves in only 347 ms. I can't figure out what is wrong with the `(cc.uid in ["84161623"])` statement and why does adding this to the query takes 16 seconds to resolve when I already have an index on the `uid`. Any help will be appreciated.

#### update

As suggested by @cybersam I tried making the use of `USING INDEX` but that results in the following error:

```
Cannot use index hint in this context. Index hints require using an equality comparison or IN condition in WHERE (either directly or as part of a top-level AND). The comparison cannot be between two property values. Note that the label and property comparison must be specified on a non-optional node
```

Comment: please amend the output of `PROFILE <mycypherstatement>` here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `USING INDEX` clause to provide a hint to use that index. The Cypher processing code does not always automatically generate the most efficient code.

For example, put this between the `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses:

```
USING INDEX cc:Co(uuid)
```

You may also need to use additional `USING INDEX` clauses if there are other indices. Note, however, that neo4j can not use indices in all situations; and, even if it is possible, the resulting query could theoretically be slower due to other resulting changes to the query. So, take a look at the resulting profile and test the result to make sure you are happy with it.

Comment: using the above results in an error that I have added in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to do some sanity checking.

First of all, is :Co.uid an int or a string? It looks like you're addressing it as if it's a string, yet the values themselves look numeric. If it's an int, you can get rid of the quotes.

Same with :User.uid.

If you've been comparing ints to strings all this time, try fixing that first to see if it solves the problem. If not, you'll want to start profiling and figuring out if/when the query isn't using your index.

Next, try simplifying and profiling the query to see if the indices are actually being used:

```
PROFILE MATCH (u:User {uid:"984172414"}), (cc:Co)
WHERE (cc.uid in ["84161623"])
RETURN u, cc
```

If they're both using NodeIndexSeek or NodeUniqueIndexSeek, and if the db hits seem reasonable, you might expand out to your entire path and continue profiling. However, it's worth checking for a performance improvement if you match on the start and end nodes first, like above, then try to do your additional pattern matching. For example:

```
PROFILE MATCH (u:User {uid:"984172414"}), (cc:Co)
WHERE (cc.uid in ["84161623"])
WITH u, cc
MATCH (u)-[ru:EB]->(c:Co)<-[rf:EB]-(f:User)-[rc :EB]->(cc)
WHERE (rc.from IS NOT NULL AND...
```